# Load a hierarchical object with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, hierarchical-data

I am trying to save and load hierarchical data from a database with the code first approach.

My objects :

```
public class Database
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ElementBase> elements { get; set; }
    private string XMLpath;
}

public abstract  class ElementBase : ObservableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public ElementBase() { }
    public ElementBase(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

    public class Element : ElementBase
{
    protected string type;
    public virtual List<ElementBase> elements { get; set;}
}
    public class Attribute : ElementBase
{
    private string value;
    private byte editable;
}
```

My object "Database" contain a list of "ElementBase". The "ElementBase" is build on the composite pattern.

In my context i only have the "Database".

```
public  DbSet<NWViewer.Model.Database> Databases { get; set; }
```

I save the Database on the sqlserver like that :

```
public static void add(NW.Database db)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            dbContext.Databases.Add(db);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

It create a Database and an ElementBase table on the server :

[image: Table Diagram]

And finally when i try to get a database it retrieve only the database with the first child Element :

```
    public static NW.Database update (NW.Database db)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
        {

            var originalDB = (from d in dbContext.Databases
                                         where d.ID == db.ID
                                         select d).First();
            dbContext.Entry(originalDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(db);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return originalDB;
        }
    }
```

the error when it try to get the child of the first Element :

> Message   "Le jeu d'entités ou l'importation de fonction
>   'Element_elements' n'est pas défini dans le conteneur d'entités
>   'DatabaseContext'. Rapproché identificateur placé dans une séquence
>   d'échappement, ligne 1, colonne 73."  string

Dav

Answer (score 0):

The error come from the attributes i have exposed in the "Element" object. They was :

```
    public class Element : ElementBase
    {
      protected string type;
      public virtual List<ElementBase> elements { get; set;}

      public List<ElementBase> Elements
      {
          get { return this.elements; }
      }
    }
```

This was a bit stupid and EF didn't know how to link that. I have simply removed  the "Elements" and it get all the child.